# Flex-box is stretched out

Tags: css, flexbox

In this example, I am trying to make an image gallery the problem is that the boxes from 1 to 9 are stretched down as you can see in the snippet.

I want to set them with a fixed size.
I tried align-content and align-items and still no result.

If I change the size of the browser the boxes are back to normal like this
[image]

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.inner .box');
const cursors = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor')

cursors.forEach( c => {
  c.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
      if(menu[i].classList.contains('scale')){
        if(c.innerText == "<"){
          if(i == 0){
            menu[0].classList.remove('scale')
            menu[menu.length - 1].classList.add('scale')
            break
          }
          menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
          menu[i-1].classList.add('scale')
          break
        }
        else if(c.innerText == ">"){
          if(i == menu.length - 1){
            menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
            menu[0].classList.add('scale')
            break
          }
          menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
          menu[i+1].classList.add('scale')
          break
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:90vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%,  rgba(0,93,133,1) 0%, rgba(0,181,149,1) 90% );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: GradientAnimated 59s ease infinite;
}

.container{
  margin-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  padding:-1px;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;  
}
.container.inner{
  margin-top:0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
.box{
  width: 15vw;
  height: 40vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.box1{background-color:#f00;}
.box2{background-color:#fa0;flex-grow:1;}
.box3{background-color:#ff0;}
.box4{background-color:#080;}
.box5{background-color:#00f;}
.box6{background-color:#6ae;}
.box7{background-color:#90d;}
.box8{background-color:#408;}

.box.scale:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor{
  color: #222;
}

.cursor:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: shake 1s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both infinite;
}

.scale{
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  animation-name: Scale;
  animation-timing-function:ease;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes Scale{
  from{transform: scale(1);}
  to{transform: scale(1.5);}
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes GradientAnimated {
    0%{background-position:0% 10%}
    50%{background-position:100% 91%}
    100%{background-position:0% 10%}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box cursor">
    <</div>
      <div class="container inner">
        <div class="box box1 scale">1</div>
        <div class="box box2">2</div>
        <div class="box box3">3</div>
        <div class="box box4">4</div>
        <div class="box box5">5</div>
        <div class="box box6">6</div>
        <div class="box box7">7</div>
        <div class="box box8">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box cursor">></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have `height: 40vh;` wouldn't that be the issue ? *If I change the size of the browser the boxes are back to normal like this* because `vh` is relative to the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max-height instead of height otherwise it will use that height.

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.inner .box');
const cursors = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor')

cursors.forEach(c => {
  c.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      if (menu[i].classList.contains('scale')) {
        if (c.innerText == "<") {
          if (i == 0) {
            menu[0].classList.remove('scale')
            menu[menu.length - 1].classList.add('scale')
            break
          }
          menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
          menu[i - 1].classList.add('scale')
          break
        } else if (c.innerText == ">") {
          if (i == menu.length - 1) {
            menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
            menu[0].classList.add('scale')
            break
          }
          menu[i].classList.remove('scale')
          menu[i + 1].classList.add('scale')
          break
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, rgba(0, 93, 133, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 181, 149, 1) 90%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: GradientAnimated 59s ease infinite;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  padding: -1px;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container.inner {
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 15vw;
  max-height: 40vh; /*  you need to add max-height instead of height */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: #fa0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: #ff0;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: #080;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: #6ae;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: #90d;
}

.box8 {
  background-color: #408;
}

.box.scale:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  color: #222;
}

.cursor:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: shake 1s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both infinite;
}

.scale {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  animation-name: Scale;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes Scale {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes GradientAnimated {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 10%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 91%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 10%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box cursor">
    <</div>
      <div class="container inner">
        <div class="box box1 scale">1</div>
        <div class="box box2">2</div>
        <div class="box box3">3</div>
        <div class="box box4">4</div>
        <div class="box box5">5</div>
        <div class="box box6">6</div>
        <div class="box box7">7</div>
        <div class="box box8">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box cursor">></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the styling of the boxes either use, **fixed units** for height or use **max-height** instead of height.

It should either look like this:-

```
.box{
height: 300px;
}
```

Or it should look like this:-

```
.box{
max-height: 40vh;
}
```

> Using the **max-height** method is more preferable because you don't have to define other flex properties like Shrink And Grow.